# Simplest HTML5 template for examples in print

Tags: templates, html

I'm going to be printing out a bunch of HTML5 examples that will be presented in a book format. With this constraint, space is at a premium, so every line I can remove is helpful. I'd like a minimal setup that is clear, but correct, and won't steer anyone down the wrong path.

This is the template I have so far:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- examples... -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

I see `<meta charset="utf-8">` in every html5 template on the web. Obviously it's best practice to keep it in, but is it so important that I can't remove it, even if it doesn't affect the examples I've provided. Likewise with `<!doctype html>`.

I could always provide a more robust example in the introduction, but as I expect people to cut-and-paste examples, I'd prefer to have them in a good, but concise, form. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for helping you write a book.  But in any case, try Barnes and Noble if you have one nearby.  They are bound to have some great HTML books you can flip through.  QuickStart from Peach Pit Press is always a favorite for simple / easy-to-follow introductions to various tech like HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to have the DOCTYPE, otherwise HTML5 type stuff won't work in certain browsers (notably IE9).  It would probably be safe to leave out the charset - it's not like you can guarantee what charset your readers will be saving the examples in anyway.  You will have to add a `title` element to the `head` - the document is not valid without it.